# VB.Net DataGridview Master/Detail updating failing to remain consistent

Tags: datagridview, master-detail, basic

I have a vb.net application that talks to a Microsoft Access backend.  On one form I have a `datagridview`, and beneath that a number of "detail" fields; these were generated by dragging onto the form, so there's autogenerated code, and it pretty much works: If I click on a row in the `datagridview`, the detail fields show that data, and if I change the data (by typing) in any of the detail fields (these are `textboxes`, `comboboxes`, etc.) the data changes in the `datagridview`.
NB - I've made the `datagridview` read-only, so that all user changes must run through the detail fields, where I do a lot of consistency checking.  So far, all good.

The problem that has arisen is that if I *programmatically* change some of the detail fields, that data doesn't show up in the datagridview.  I want to do this if data is entered into certain fields - imagine someone entering birthdate, and I want to update an Age field (this is notional; that'd be silly, but the mechanism is the same).  In that example I might set `Agetextbox.text = "52"` or something, but that data doesn't show up in the datagridview.  If I *type* "52" into that field the datagridview *does* update.

This is all happening before I push the data back out to the database - indeed I don't want to commit these changes until the user has filled in nearly all of the fields, or at least they're all valid - so it isn't an issue of updating the database and reading the data back in.  It's merely an issue of having two (I thought) identically-bound controls show the same data.

A detail that might be important - the programmatic update works for the first 4 or 5 columns in the datagridview, then not for the rest of them.  No error is thrown, but to me it is suspicious that the updating seems to proceed for a few fields and then stop.  This is where I've been digging so far, with no luck.

I'll again try to dig into the autogenerated code to see if I can spot an answer, but I'd appreciate any wisdom anyone has.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening in your application without the code.

Comment: Minor formatting changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a bindingsource.endedit() after the programmatic updates fixes the problem.